# Remove UIViewController from memory after Modal Segue

Tags: ios, memory, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm On UIViewController 'A'. I'm presenting(Modally - Cross Dissolve) UIViewController 'B'.

After 'B' is presented, When i touch/tap the View, `TouchesBegan` of 'A' is triggered. So i figured i need to remove 'A' from memory after 'B' is presented.

I tried :

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "gameLevel"
        {
            if let viewController: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {

                self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Dosent seem's to work. Any suggestion how to **remove 'A' from memory after i moved to 'B'?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you should. If you are presenting a view controller, your user experience design should let the user go back to it. This is intended design; don't use `presentViewController:animated` if you don't want this experience.

Furthermore, there is no hack in the SDK to do this either. This will be very apparent to you if you check the documentation, the `presentingViewController` is a strong reference.

What you may want is to remove all the view hierarchy and set `rootViewController` property of your app delegate. You may not get the animation; but the underlying view controller *might* get deallocated.

Comment: Hey Avi, Thank you. I'm not using presentViewController:animated, I'm using "performSegueWithIdentifier". Actually, the main reason im using it, and not presentViewController:animated it's because the animation i'm generating using it. I haven't fully understand what is the difference between Modal to presentViewController, but i think that using presentViewController the previous UIViewcontroller deallocated. Bottom line, How can i keep the modal presentation, but prevent this "TouchesBean" method occurs on the previous UIViewController?

Comment: Modal presentation == `presentViewController:animated`

Comment: Can you please expand? and where to place the code exactly?

Comment: What I am trying to say is that can't stop that from happening. It is how it works -- and it is how it *should* work. `presentViewController:animated` isn't your solution here. 
So, instead of perform segue, you can call `setRootViewController` instead.

Comment: Generally, Modal presentation placing the UIViewController Above the previous one? If i'm "rewind" back to 'A', will it reload from ViewControllerdidLoad() , or will it not trigger it again?

Comment: If you re(un)wind to `A`, `viewDidLoad` will not get called. `viewWillAppear` will get called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97897/discussion-between-avismara-and-roi-mulia).